# Propositional equivalence. Duality problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I recently have started practicing problems on Discrete Mathematics by Keneth H.Rosen. There seems to be an interesting problem on Propositional Equivalence which states that when is $s^{*} = s$. Where s is a compound proposition and $s^{*}$ is the dual of $s$.

Comment: $s^*$ is the formula obtained from $s$ by exchanging the symbols $\vee$ and $\wedge$?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I was thinking of is s* = s whenever s* <-> s is a tautology. Correct me if I am wrong.

Looking for suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that just what = means here? So it doesn't seem to say much in a way. I think the question is looking for an explanation in the shape of the formula itself. Is (p and not p) or q an example of such a formula?

Comment: Yes, I proved it by applying demorgan's law on $\neg p \vee \neg q$ gives $\neg (p \wedge q)$, so $(\neg p \vee \neg q) \leftrightarrow \neg (p \wedge q)$ is indeed Tautology.

Answer (score 0):

If $s$ has any occurrences of $∧,∨, T, or F$, then the process of forming the dual will change it. Then $s^∗=s$ if and only if $s$ is one propositional variable.

N.B: I have recently started learning discrete mathematics and solved this problem a few days ago. :)